# Selenium Python ошибка

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, selenium-webdriver

Начал изучать библиотеку Selenium на Python версии 4.8 и встретил первую ошибку непонятно связанную с чем.

Вот код:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D:\\programm\\scraping\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.google.ru/?hl=ru')
```

Когда я его запускаю, по началу вроде всё нормально, но во время выполнения(погрузки страницы) в консоли выходят такие ошибки:

```
PS D:\programm\scraping\selenium> & C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe d:/programm/scraping/selenium/pars.py
d:\programm\scraping\selenium\pars.py:3: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D:\\programm\\scraping\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe')

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:49963/devtools/browser/b3d71018-8c47-42eb-91ce-116576590c7f
[10576:8344:0414/181358.998:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(992)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[10576:8344:0414/181359.007:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(992)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[10576:8344:0414/181359.137:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(992)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[10576:8344:0414/181359.403:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(992)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[10576:8344:0414/181359.431:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(992)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[10576:8344:0414/181359.570:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(992)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
PS D:\programm\scraping\selenium>
```

И по завершению прогрузки страницы (или она даже не успевает прогрузиться до конца, не могу уловить данный момент) браузер просто закрывается, хотя по гайдам на ютубе смотрю, ни у кого не закрывается по завершении выполнения кода.

Версии хрома и драйвера совпадают.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данная ошибка может быть связана с использованием параметра `executable_path` в конструкторе `webdriver.Chrome`, о чем и говорит предупреждение. Разработчики предлагают использовать объект класса `Service`. Мне кажется, использование этого объекта может решить данную проблему.

Для этого, чтобы использовать объект `Service` вместо аргумента `executable_path`, вам нужно:

1. Убедиться, что версия библиотеки `selenium` - 4.0.0 или больше:

```
pip3 install -U selenium
```

2. Убедиться, что установлен *Webdriver Manager* для Python:

```
pip3 install webdriver-manager
```

3. Для того, чтобы перенести код на совместимый с актуальной версией `selenium`, вам нужно изменить его следующим образом:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://www.google.ru/?hl=ru")
```

Также ваша проблема может быть связана с неполадками в SSL. Вы можете проверить, не устарели ли сертификаты на вашем устройстве

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin я не отрицаю, что стиль ответа может быть похож на сгенерированный нейросетью, но я это писал своими руками. в качестве источника использовал [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70099102/13283436) со StackOverflow

Comment: @diduk001 подозрения вызывают не только стилистика, но и скорость ответов. Например 14 апреля у вас два ответа один в 15:46, второй в 15:48, 2 минуты разница. Конечно же, не исключён вариант, что вы их писали в параллели и потом опубликовали, но если в совокупности факторов вскроется использование chatGPT, будет моментальный бан.

Comment: @DiMithras я действительно иногда пишу два ответа параллельно. Спасибо за понимание

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

Решение крылось в том, что в `Selenium 4.0+` вырезали возможность указывать путь до драйвера в атрибуте `executable_path`.

Сейчас разработчики предлагают указать этот путь через объект класса `Service` и вот как я это исправил:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

s=Service('D:\programm\scraping\selenium\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

driver.get("'https://www.google.ru/?hl=ru'")
```

Конечно этот код не обладает лучшим синтаксисом, но проблема была решена!

*P.S. перед использованием объекта `Service` убедитесь, что вы установили **Webdriver Manager***